# Ruby on Rails child with multiple parents options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, web-frameworks

I encountered against the typical case of a model (Address) and multiple models having this data (Company, Person). Let's work with these models as example, but can be generalized with any others.

Making the correct choice is important, as changing the database schema or making deep changes are not easy later.

Initially it will be one-to-one association, then we have these possibilities:

1) Use the classical normalization and put all the address data into each model requiring it. Then create an address subform for render partial into each one, and put the code behavior into a Module to be called from each model controller using it.
This could looks fine, but it has the problem that is hard to make changes, as any change in the Address data needs to be done on each model using it. Also hard to change it to a one-to-many association, if required.

2) Rails polymorphic feature. Address is a model itself, and belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true, then Company and Person have has_one/has_many :address/:addresses, as :addressable. Then add the polymorphic FK to Address table and it's done.
I like this solution, it is clear and with only 2 extra columns we have done it. The only contra I can think about is we rely in a framework feature, so if someday we migrate to another one, it should feature polymorphic too. Well this is not really true because we can always make the SQL manually searching by addressable_type = "type", but I think is not database design standard.

3) Join tables. One for each parent. So we have JT_Company_Address, JT_Person_Address, and we use the Rails has_one/has_many :through associations using those join tables.
I think using join tables is more database design standard, but add some extra tables.

4) Reverse the relationship, making Address the parent and each of the other a child. So each child would have a FK address_id.
I don't like much this one, as I will handle mainly companies and persons, and then look up their address if required, not the opposite, looking addresses and then loop up what it has in it. We can always use the bidiriectional association using the Rails inverse_of, but at database layer Address would be the parent one anycase.

My favorites at this moment are 2 and 3. I will probably use Rails and not move from it, so the polymorphic looks very easy and clean.

Then, what do you think, which one is the best one? Any advice is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: If `Address` will belong only to one entity (as stated on your question) i'll go with #2; on the other hand, if multiple entities can have the same address, then i'll go with #4.

Comment: Can't be shared. So probably #2 is fine. Thanks.